# elasticsearch: how to keep populating field after creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a AWS ES instance with a [10MB Maximum Size of HTTP Request Payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html), and I have a record that will populate a ES field with more than 10MB, so I would like for a way that maybe I can keep populating a field once it is already created inside the ES index

I am doing something like this for creation:

```
curl -XPUT 'https://myinstance.amazonaws.com/index_name/doc_type/<item.id>?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "title": <title>,
    "description": <description with more than 10MB>,
    "date": <mydate>,
    "extra_id": <extra_id>,
}
'
```

Now, let's my description is something like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin placerat non massa non tempor. Pellentesque vitae lacus libero. Aenean porta hendrerit ante sed consequat. Nunc blandit iaculis mauris quis varius. Sed at est in felis mollis varius. Vivamus iaculis at dui a pellentesque. Nulla vitae aliquam sem, vel finibus odio. Nullam sed dictum sem. Nullam venenatis tortor nec imperdiet feugiat.
>
> Cras eget semper sapien. Maecenas iaculis nibh ut blandit lobortis. Proin scelerisque risus nec velit vulputate pulvinar. Donec id egestas sapien. Ut id eros cursus, ultrices nisi sit amet, auctor justo. Etiam venenatis tincidunt est id hendrerit. Curabitur urna nisi, tincidunt id sem quis, laoreet scelerisque magna. Cras sit amet nunc eget sem vestibulum posuere id ac sapien...

I would like to create my record with only the first paragraph, and later include the second paragraph with a second request (I'll take care of the splitting of the text). Is there a way to do that with ElasticSearch?